# Bash 'date -d' bug?

Tags: linux, bash, date, ubuntu-10.04

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. In bash I am getting error while converting string to date like this:

```
date -d '20110327 02:00'
date: invalid date `20110327 02:00'
```

but these work:

```
date -d '20110327 03:00'
Sun Mar 27 03:00:00 CEST 2011

date -d '20110326 02:00'
Sat Mar 26 02:00:00 CET 2011

date -d '20110328 02:00'
Mon Mar 28 02:00:00 CEST 2011
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 6):

It's the summer time !
In 2011, we get an additionnal hour on the March 27th at 2:00 it was in fact 3:00.
So 27/03/2011 2:00 is not a valid date :-)

Comment: `data` had a nice catch on this one. I would not have guessed that alone.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, I'm sure there was a transition to/from Daylight Saving Time (DST) at 2:00 that day, so there wasn't 2:00 :)

Answer (score 3):

Well there is no such local time - there was switch to summer time and the clock went from 1:59 to 3:00.